# Rewriterule won't work due to folder name conflict

Tags: mod-rewrite, directory, url-rewriting

I need to redirect mywebsite.com/admin to mywebsite.com/login.php, but the url in browser should stay mywebsite.com/admin. I use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin$ [NC]
RewriteRule admin login.php [NC,L]
```

But it won't work because I have "admin" folder in my website root folder. It keeps entering the folder and listing files. When I delete "admin" folder, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this message board is only for simple, dumb questions... Every time I've asked something complicated, no one answered. I'm wondering if there's even one expert participating in these discussions...